# I'm having issues getting my 2D matrix to output correctly using file inputs in Java

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I've been working on a coding project where  The output of the program is two 2D arrays of similarity scores. The first array contains similarity scores among songs and is written to the file named in command-line argument #3. If there are N songs, then the array should be NxN. The first row contains the similarity betweensong #1 and every other song in order (so the first element of this array is the similarity of song#1 to itself). The second row contains similarity scores between song #2 and every other song, and so on. In general, element [i,j] is the similarity in responses of songs i and j. The second array is the same thing, only for users, not songs, and it is written to the file named in command-line argument #4. Thus if there are M cooperative users, there should be M rows of
length M, where element [i,j] is the similarity in responses of users i and j.

Where I've bee having issues is either the normalization, the calculation of mean and standard deviation, or the building of the similarity matrix. Or alternatively a combination of the three. I can get the file to output the correct size depending on the input but always give incorrect calculations and duplicates them across both output files.

```
    // Method to calculate the mean ranks for each user
    private static Map<Integer, Double> calculateMeanRanks(Map<Integer, Map<Integer, Integer>> userSongRanks) {
        Map<Integer, Double> meanRanks = new HashMap<>();
        userSongRanks.forEach((userId, songRanks) -> {
            double average = songRanks.values().stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).average().orElse(0.0);
            meanRanks.put(userId, average);
        });
        return meanRanks;
    }
```

```
    // Method to calculate the standard deviation of ranks for each user
    private static Map<Integer, Double> calculateStdDevRanks(Map<Integer, Map<Integer, Integer>> userSongRanks, Map<Integer, Double> meanRanks) {
        Map<Integer, Double> stdDevRanks = new HashMap<>();
        userSongRanks.forEach((userId, songRanks) -> {
            double mean = meanRanks.get(userId);
            double sumSquared = songRanks.values().stream().mapToDouble(rank -> Math.pow(rank - mean, 2)).sum();
            double stdDev = Math.sqrt(sumSquared / songRanks.size());
            stdDevRanks.put(userId, stdDev);
        });
        return stdDevRanks;
    }
```

```
    // Method to normalize the ranks
    public static Map<Integer, Map<Integer, Double>> normalizeRanks(Map<Integer, Map<Integer, Integer>> userSongRanks) {
        // Calculate mean and standard deviation for each user
        Map<Integer, Double> meanRanks = calculateMeanRanks(userSongRanks);
        Map<Integer, Double> stdDevRanks = calculateStdDevRanks(userSongRanks, meanRanks);
    
        Map<Integer, Map<Integer, Double>> normalizedRanks = new HashMap<>();
    
        // Normalize each user's rankings
        for (Map.Entry<Integer, Map<Integer, Integer>> userEntry : userSongRanks.entrySet()) {
            Integer userId = userEntry.getKey();
            Map<Integer, Integer> songRanks = userEntry.getValue();
    
            double userMean = meanRanks.get(userId);
            double userStdDev = stdDevRanks.get(userId);
    
            Map<Integer, Double> userNormalizedRanks = new HashMap<>();
    
            for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> songEntry : songRanks.entrySet()) {
                Integer songId = songEntry.getKey();
                Integer rank = songEntry.getValue();
    
                // Avoid division by zero in case stdDev is 0
                double normalizedRank = userStdDev == 0 ? 0 : (rank - userMean) / userStdDev;
                userNormalizedRanks.put(songId, normalizedRank);
            }
    
            normalizedRanks.put(userId, userNormalizedRanks);
        }
    
        return normalizedRanks;
    }
```

```
    public static double calculateSimilarity(Map<Integer, Double> scoresA, Map<Integer, Double> scoresB) {
        return scoresA.entrySet().stream()
            .filter(entry -> scoresB.containsKey(entry.getKey()))
            .mapToDouble(entry -> entry.getValue() * scoresB.get(entry.getKey()))
            .sum();
    }
```

I've come up with a few different expected output files

Expected song output

```
2.184794234 -0.182407192 -1.304394327 -0.906889871 0.208897156
-0.182407192 4.563879201 -3.168921956 -4.167733602 2.955183549
-1.304394327 -3.168921956 3.434968612 3.511617453 -2.473269782
-0.906889871 -4.167733602 3.511617453 5.035087447 -3.472081428
0.208897156 2.955183549 -2.473269782 -3.472081428 2.78127050
```

Expected user output

```
4 3.772968873 2.555660573 3.200378765 1.490711985
3.772968873 4 3.337763467 3.54648278 0.766964989
2.555660573 3.337763467 4 3.557174642 0
3.200378765 3.54648278 3.557174642 4 0.550481883
1.490711985 0.766964989 0 0.550481883 2
```

based on the input

song file

```
We Are the Champions
Toxic
Billie Jean
Hotel California
La Tortura
```

and rating file

```
3 4 5 4 3
5 5 5 5 5
3 3 2 1 0
2 2 2 2 0
5 5 4 5 4
```

I've tried to simplify and refactor the methods as much as I could and something still isn't coming out correctly. Any help would be appreciated.